# Asp.Net (old): The requested security protocol is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

Earlier my application used .net 3.5, but then I upgraded it to 4.8.

I add this code to support secure:

```
      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol|= SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault|
                                             SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 |
                                             SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                             SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                             SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
                                             SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;

                HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(HelpURL + path) as HttpWebRequest;
                req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                req.PreAuthenticate = true;
                req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                var statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()).StatusCode;
```

And it is works with https, but not with http!

```
The requested security protocol is not supported
```

How to allow works with http?

**SOLUTION:**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        try
        {         
                Uri validatedUri = null;
                var result = Uri.TryCreate(_path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out validatedUri);
                if (result)
                {
                    HelpURL = path;

                    if(HelpURL.StartsWith("https://"))
                    {
                        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault |
                                                SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 |
                                                SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                                SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                                SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
                                                SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
                    }

                }
    }
```

Comment: **Use a URL with http://..**? The ServicePointManager security protocols should not apply to plain HTTP which is not encrypted.

Comment: @user2864740, yes i use http://

Comment: Post a minimal working example, including an *actual* HTTP demo URL that can be tested (this is about problem reproduction and/or refinement, I don’t want/care what the actual code uses). Anyway, if the HTTP request is *automatically upgraded* to HTTPS (see 301/302/307 redirects), then it might throw such an exception on the secondary (now HTTPS) request.

Comment: @user2864740, it works. you can post an answer. i add work solution on my answer